# Trouble getting the (int) value of a header byte from a bmp image when it is bigger than 127 pixels

Tags: c#, bitmap, ascii, bmp

I'm trying to get the size of a generic .bmp. However, when the image is bigger than 127 pixels, the bytes become weird. (I'm opening the images with a text editor then pasting the contents in an online character-to-text converter because when in this situation my C# program will just print a "0".)
Here are the relevant bytes for a 127-tall image:

```
127 032 032 032
```

Clearly, the image is 127 pixels tall.

Here are the relevant bytes for a 128-tall image:

```
226 130 172 032 032 032
```

What happened here? If 128 is the limit, shouldn't it become "0 1 032 032"? My thinking is that the value in the data would be something like 226*(base^0) + 130*(base^1) + 172*(base^2), but I think that would be at least greater than 226.
Thank you for reading.

Edit: I checked the hex values instead (with Notepad++), and the number seems right. But why does it become messed up when transformed to an integer (for this I use C#'s what I believe to be called "typecasting", "(int)")?

```
string line;
try
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("E:\\Test15.bmp");
    line = sr.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<line.Length; i++)
        {
            if(i==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Header");
                Console.Write("\tSignature: ");
            }
            if(i==2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tFile size: ");
            }
            if(i==6)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tReserved: ");
            }
            if(i==10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tData offset: ");
            }
            if(i==14)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Info header:");
                Console.Write("\tHeader size: ");
            }
            if(i==18)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tImage width: ");
            }
            if (i == 22)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tImage height: ");
            }
            if (i == 26)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tNumber of color planes: ");
            }
            if (i == 28)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tBits per pixel: ");
            }
            if(i==30)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tCompression: ");
            }
            if(i==34)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tImage size: ");
            }
            if(i==38)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tX resolution: ");
            }
            if (i == 42)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tY resolution: ");
            }
            if (i == 46)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tPixels per meter: ");
            }
            if (i == 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.Write("\tNumber of colors: ");
            }
            if (i == 54)
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }
            if (i <= 53)
            {
                //Console.Write(i + ": ");
                if ((int)line[i] == 65533)
                {
                    Console.Write("0 ");
                }
                if ((int)line[i] != 65533)
                {
                    Console.Write((int)line[i] + " ");
                }
            }
            
            if (i>53)
            {
                if((int)line[i] < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.Write((int)line[i + 0]);
                Console.Write(" ");
                if ((int)line[i+2] < 10)
                {
                    Console.Write(" ");
                }
                Console.Write((int)line[i + 2]);
                Console.Write("   ");
                if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                i = i + 2;
            }
        }
    }
    sr.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
}
finally
{
    Console.WriteLine("Executing \"finally\" block.");
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are reading text and converting chars to ints? What do you expect as a result for `(int)'a'`?

Comment: Maybe 97 (ASCII decimal)

Comment: Did you try to debug and check what the first `line` looks like? According to [BMP file header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header) it should begin with one of `"BM"/"BA"/"CI"/"CP"/"IC"/"PT"`, then you should have 4 bytes for the file size

Comment: Yes, I did some experiments. Opening a 12x12 picture gives this result: Header
        Signature: 66 77
        File size: 0 1 0 0
        Reserved: 0 0 0 0
        Data offset: 54 0 0 0

Info header:
        Header size: 40 0 0 0
        Image width: 12 0 0 0
        Image height: 12 0 0 0
        Number of color planes: 1 0
        Bits per pixel: 24 0
        Compression: 0 0 0 0
        Image size: 0 1 0 0
        X resolution: 0 0 0 0
        Y resolution: 0 0 0 0
        Pixels per meter: 0 0 0 0
        Number of colors: 0 0 0 0 --- Sorry, I can't format very well.

Comment: I guess the file size is a bit strange, but the pixel size works so that's enough for me. The problem comes with an image that is 128 pixels. It produces this:  Header
        Signature: 66 77
        File size: 54 36 0 0
        Reserved: 0 0 0 0
        Data offset: 54 0 0 0

Info header:
        Header size: 40 0 0 0
        Image width: 24 0 0 0
        Image height: 0 0 0 0
        Number of color planes: 1 0
        Bits per pixel: 24 0
        Compression: 0 0 0 0
        Image size: 0 36 0 0
        X resolution: 0 14 0 0
        Y resolution: 0 14 0 0

Comment: Pixels per meter: 0 0 0 0
        Number of colors: 0 0 0 0 ---- checking with a website, it says the image height is "226 130 172", which i dont understand, but when looking at the hex value with notepad++ it says those bytes are "80", which translates to 128, the correct size. I don't know how it goes from 80 to 226 130 172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I just tried your code with a white bmp image of size 339x103 and this is what I got:

```
Header
        Signature: 66 77
        File size: 0 69 0 0
        Reserved: 0 0 0 0
        Data offset: 118 0 0 0

Info header:
        Header size: 40 0 0 0
        Image width: 83 1 0 0
        Image height: 103 0 0 0
        Number of color planes: 1 0
        Bits per pixel: 4 0
        Compression: 0 0 0 0
        Image size: 52 69 0 0
        X resolution: 0 0 0 0
        Y resolution: 0 0 0 0
        Pixels per meter: 0 0 0 0
        Number of colors: 0 0 0 0
```

Considering the fact that "[*All of the integer values are stored in little-endian format (i.e. least-significant byte first)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header)", that line:

```
        Image width: 83 1 0 0
```

should be read: `83 + 1*256 + 0*256^2 + 0*256^3 = 339` which is the expected width...

However, there is indeed a problem when byte value is between 128 and 255, because then `(int)line[i]` will resolve to 65533. I suggest reading bytes from file instead of lines, in order to get rid of this problem. See [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Yes, this works for some reason, I get the same numbers. Could you try it with an image that is 24x128?

Comment: The real problem lies in encoding, you have the error when size is between 128 and 255 because `(int)(char)128` gives 65533

Comment: Is there any way around this?

Comment: I'd say maybe try to directly read bytes from file instead of lines. Check [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes?view=net-7.0)

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, I think this [msdn thread about .net vs .net core supported encodings](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/aspnet/en-US/d0885eba-6fab-4ba1-aba9-9d92e03748ff/c-which-is-the-correct-encoding-type?forum=csharpgeneral) is worth reading